# getting the wrong result when executed

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have doubt regarding functions and arrays. when i pass a value of 3 in index 1 the result we get is 0 and it's the same for passing a value of 4 at index 3. but, the answer i am getting when executed is 22. I don't understand why? can anyone explain me what i have missed.

```
var puzzlers = [
function ( a ) { return 8*a - 10; }, 
function ( a ) { return (a-3) * (a-3) * (a-3); }, 
function ( a ) { return a * a + 4; },
function ( a ) { return a % 5; }
];

alert(puzzlers[puzzlers[1](3)](puzzlers[3](9) ) );
```

Comment: nash_ag's answer is right. If you don't think so, maybe you are considering `puzzlers[1]` to be the first in your array which it is not. The index range of your array is [0-3].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code (and answer) are doing the right thing. You need to break down what is happening into steps, starting at the inner-most. So, with your question:

```
alert(puzzlers[puzzlers[1](3)](puzzlers[3](9) ) );
```

Look at:

```
// puzzlers[3](9) is 4
alert(puzzlers[puzzlers[1](3)](4) );
```

Then look at:

```
// puzzlers[1](3) is 0
alert(puzzlers[0](4));
```

The solution is then:

```
alert(4*8 - 10);
```

Which is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the right result:

```
alert(puzzlers[puzzlers[1](3)](puzzlers[3](9)));
```

`puzzlers[3](9)` evaluates to `4` and `puzzlers[1](3)` evaluates to `0`. So the final result would be `puzzlers[0](4)` which is `8*4 - 10` i.e. `22`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us why you get the wrong result? What was your expected answer?
The question you asked displays 22 (as what PM 77-1 said).

Comment: I said wrong result because when i evaluated manually i made an error which was clarified .